# Is this a correct phrase? Does it feel friendly?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I am working in Sweden right now, and a suggestion has come up to use a global tagline for a project. It's to get everyone talking in a long term discussion about company culture and teamwork, etc.  The line is:

"Join the dialogue"

Now for Swedes this sounds fine and dialogue is a friendly word - in Swedish. But for me, as a native speaker,  it feels formal and stiff. But I see it in lots of places on the net, and the more I hear it I think , well, its ok. Any opinions? It should be a warm invitation for everyone to get involved, but its a rather serious issue as well.

Comment: Your instinct that it sounds, not unfriendly, but stilted, is correct. More idiomaticall, we'd invite people to "*join the conversation*" or "*join in the conversation*".

Comment: How about "Vi uppskattar din feedback, men inte lika mycket som vi ogillar det"?

Comment: Ha, ha, very funny, maybe I can use that in my persuasive arguments against just that phrase. :)  Thanks for the input, now I can go out a bit more confidently in my discussions, or dialogues even conversations? - or I could just talk about it, I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds formal, rather than unfriendly. For something more inviting try 'Join the conversation'